# where is bin/elasticsearch on kuberenetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, elasticsearch-x-pack

I have installed elasticsearch on kubernetes using the helm chart
. I need to enable xpack security for that I need to create a certificate using elasticsearch-certutil. I can't find it's location on kubernetes.

the error I am getting now

```
2019-06-25T10:20:56.882057213Z "Caused by:
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to initialize a TrustManagerFactory",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882063036Z "atorg.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.StoreTrustConfig.createTrustManager(StoreTrustConfig.java:61) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882068596Z "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.createSslContext(SSLService.java:382) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882074256Z "at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1133) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882079897Z "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.lambda$loadSSLConfigurations$2(SSLService.java:426) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882085280Z "at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1333) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882120138Z "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSSLConfigurations(SSLService.java:423) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882136977Z "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:119) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882143717Z "at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.<init>(XPackPlugin.java:144) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882149641Z "at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882155163Z "at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882168785Z "at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882175111Z "at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882181018Z "at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882228253Z "at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:605) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882234700Z "at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:556) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882240443Z "at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:471) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882246040Z "at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882251927Z "at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:308) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882257697Z "at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882263355Z "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882271710Z "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:211) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882318705Z "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:325) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
I 2019-06-25T10:20:56.882344091Z "at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]",
```

this is my configuration esConfig:

```
elasticsearch.yml: |
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsea/config/certs/ca.p12
```

xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.p12
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/ca.p12

I used kubectl exec -it elasticsearch-master-0 -- /bin/bash to enter the container and generate certificate in the exact path /usr/share/elasticsearch/certs

Comment: Are you checking for `/bin/elasticsearch` inside the elasticsearch pods?

Comment: I want to create the elasticsearch certificate the only ay mentioned in elasticsearch officiel documents is using bin/elasticsearch so yes I am looking to dounf bin/elasticsearch

Comment: Can you provide output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`?

Comment: NAMESPACE     NAME          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default       elasticsearch-master-0      2/2     Running            0          41h
default       elasticsearch-master-1      2/2     Running            0          3d22h
default       elasticsearch-master-2      1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   152        14h
default       kibana-kibana-679655c849-qmqjs      0/1     Running     0          14h

Comment: there is a path mentioned on kubernetes /usr/share/elasticsearch/config but I can't access it on the shell can you pklease help with that

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using [helm charts](https://github.com/helm/charts) you need to set all those things inside your template.

First you should make yourself familiar with https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch

Second you will need to check what is wrong with one of your pods `elasticsearch-master-2` because it's `CrashLoopBackOff`.
You can do that using `kubectl describe pods elasticsearch-master-2` and check events at the bottom.

As for Xpack and [Enabling elasticsearch interal monitoring](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch#enabling-elasticsearch-internal-monitoring):

> Requires version 6.3+ and standard non  `oss`  repository defined. Starting with 6.3 Xpack is partially free and enabled by default. You need to set a new config to enable the collection of these internal metrics. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/monitoring-settings.html)
>
> To do this through this helm chart override with the three following changes:
>
> ```
> image.repository: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
> cluster.xpackEnable: true
> cluster.env.XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED: true
> ```
>
> Note: to see these changes you will need to update your kibana repo to  `image.repository: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana`  instead of the  `oss`  version

You should also read [Get a Shell to a Running Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/), which explains you can connect to a `pod`.

**In Your example** using `kubectl exec -it elasticsearch-master-0 -- /bin/bash`

Comment: thank you very much sir I am trying  now to create a certification usinf the bin/esaticsearch

Comment: Please edit your question and post the errors you are getting.

Comment: I added the changes I needed I creates the certificate and then once I upgrade elasticsearch with the new values it gaves me "Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12",

Comment: xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12

Comment: esConfig:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    xpack.security.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true

Comment: xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    these are the line I added to the values file

Comment: @M.Bou please edit the "top" part which is the initial question you asked and add those errors there.

Comment: thank you crou for your help, I used a different helm chart now I reinstalled the elasticsearch using the helm chart you proposed and it's version 6.7  I want to have version 7.1.1 so I made changes on the values file : 
`appVersion: "7.1.1"` ,
`image:
  repository: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch"
  tag: "7.1.1"`  , and of course I have enabled xpack as you recommanded but I am getting this **the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured**